# My node js server stops listening on mysql db

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysqlbinlog

I implemented a listener on a table in a MySQL database with a MySQL event that is based on listening on binlog.

However, the problem is that after a while my node.js server stops listening on the database and I am getting this error when I check the db log errors:

> 2018-04-20T10:34:43.347312Z 21979 [Note] Start binlog_dump to
>   master_thread_id(21979) slave_server(12000), pos(, 453964)
>   2018-04-20T10:34:43.349066Z 21978 [Note] Aborted connection 21978 to
>   db: 'information_schema' user: '*****' host: '*****' (Got an error
>   reading communication packets)

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Can you please edit your questions and write how you did this? `listener on a table in a MySQL database with a MySQL event that is based on listening on binlog`. Thanks

Comment: i am using the mysql-event with nodeJs

Comment: A MySQL EVENT cannot send anything out from the database.  NodeJS can "poll" but it cannot "listen".  Please rephrase your question.

Comment: sir do you have a solution for that or not ??? i don't know what you are trying to do ... may be you have a problem to understand the problem !  so the mysql event listen on the bin log okay ? that's why i used listen verb ... soo please don't comment anymore in my post if you don't have any solution or something can help